# Microsoft Access Database - Search textbox form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a form which contains a textbox and a button to click on to search for a record in a specific table and show all pertaining information for the searched text. With this form I will be using it as a sub-form so I think VBA is probably the best way.

Here is my Table:

[image: Picture of Table containing data]

Here is an example of what I would like to see happen:

[image: Example]

I would like to enter a partno and click on the button and the fields will populate.

Please advise how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

On the click of the button you can set the SubForm's Recordsource to be based on the Query. It should be something like.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Me!subFrm_searchResult.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT theFields " & _
                                                FROM theTable " & _
                                                WHERE partNoFieldName = '" & 
                                                Me.partNumberTextBoxName & "'"
End Sub
```

This should be a start for you.